# importing third party packages in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a third party package which looks like this:

```
packagename
├── subfolder1
|   ├── Someclass11.py
|   ├── ...
|   └── __init__.py <- EMPTY
├── subfolder2
|   ├── Someclass21.py
|   ├── ...
|   └── __init__.py <- EMPTY
├── Someclass1.py
├── Someclass2.py
├── ...
└── __init__.py
```

`packagename/__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from packagename.subfolder1.Someclass11 import Someclass11
from packagename.subfolder2.Someclass21 import Someclass21
from packagename.Someclass1 import Someclass1
from packagename.Someclass2 import Someclass2
```

My own Project has this structure:

```
projectname
├── thirdParty
|   ├── packagename
|   └── ...
├── subfolder2
|   └── ...
├── ...
└── main.py
```

I want to include the Classes from `packagename` in my `main.py` (and in other classes/functions).
This works if I change the `packagename/__init__.py` to:

```
from projectname.thirdParty.packagename.subfolder1.Someclass11 import Someclass11
from projectname.thirdParty.packagename.subfolder2.Someclass21 import Someclass21
from projectname.thirdParty.packagename.Someclass1 import Someclass1
from projectname.thirdParty.packagename.Someclass2 import Someclass2
```

Are there solutions to import `packagename` without editing `packagename/__init__.py` and having other functions import it from different locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the `thirdParty` folder in the `PYTHONPATH`.

On Linux/MacOS:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=<path_to_projectname>/thirdParty
```

On windows:
 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7%22this%22).

An alternative to set a new pythonpath, is to add something like the following in the `main.py`, **before** importing the `thirdParty` package:

```
import sys
import os
base_dir = os.path.dirname((os.path.abspath(__file__)))
thirdParty_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'thirdParty')
sys.path.insert(0, thirdParty_dir)
```

despite this snippet can be a little version dependent (I tested it in python 3.5).